# Macro skips lines depending on insert file

Tags: vba, excel

I have a large macro which takes price book information from a vendors file, formats it and then creates a .txt file which then can be uploaded into the system. For this I prompt the user several times to select for example the column which contains information about the part number or the list price. 
So far so good. When it comes to the following code, the macro just skips it:

```
'delete rows with no price  
p = 0  
For i = 3 To LastRow  
    If p > LastRow Then  
        GoTo Ziel4  
    ElseIf IsEmpty(wsImport.Cells(i, 8)) = True Then  
        Rows(i).Delete  
        i = i - 1  
    End If  

    p = p + 1  
Next i
```

However, if I execute the code with a break point right before the loop and execute it, it works just fine. When I execute the whole script with another vendors file, it just skips 3/4 of the script and produces an empty .txt file. I already tried it with `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` to improve performance but it still keeps skipping lines.

Answer (score 1):

not so sure about your code exact goal, but since you *"prompt the user several times"* and everything works when you *"execute the code with a break point right before the loop"*, I suspect you're jumping between worksheets and hence you're prone to miss the proper worksheet

so change:

```
Rows(i).Delete
```

to:

```
wsImport.Rows(i).Delete
```

Comment: Hi there. I am worried that all of your 441 answers have been written on a mobile phone, or are using all-lower-case for aesthetic reasons. Can I encourage you to use the Shift key, and use case as per the normal English rules? This [discussion on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293779/what-is-the-most-effective-way-of-encouraging-a-user-not-to-make-deliberate-writ) is relevant.

Comment: @halfer, why are you so worried? No aesthetic reason nor 100% mobile phone writing. it's just quicker and can concentrate on the core of the answer. Anyhow  I carefully read that discussion, and the accepted answer says _"down-voting for poorly-expressed/unclear/non-useful questions"_. So if you think my answer is poorly-expressed, or unclear or non -useful, you may very well down vote it. but I'd argue that

Comment: I think my desire for readable technical writing reflects the broader opinion of the community, DN, and that includes respecting the rules of written English. You _can_ fight against it if you wish, but there aren't any good justifications for it, sorry - the community has had this discussion a great deal.

Comment: As simple as that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: My writing is readable and we’re not writing books nor fighting for Pullizer’s award. I _don’t_ fight against it, feel free to edit my answer but you are the first I meet to take it so bad. I think that efforts are better spent towards real junk q&a

Comment: @DominicLandert, you are welcome. you may then consider marking the answer as accepted. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Make sure "LastRow" has a value prior to looping as stated by "DisplayName" above, and I would assume you want to start with the last row and then move up again when searching for empty rows, otherwise it would not make much sense, right? Question is, what is p used for? Why do you increase it by 1/iteration and abort the loop if it becomes > LastRow?

Try:

```
For i = LastRow To 3 Step -1  'Start at the end and move up, should save you the "p"

    If IsEmpty(wsImport.Cells(i, 8)) = True Then  
        Rows(i).Delete  
    End If  

Next i
```

Comment: I use p to make sure the look does not get stuck as the code reaches the end of the data at some point. When this happens it gets stuck as the code permanently deletes the last row over and over again.

Comment: Sure, that's why I suggested to start at the last row and move up instead, should solve that issue as row 3 seems to be the upper row fixed.